# Performance of sc.next() and sc.nextLine()

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I was solving [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/big-sorting/problem) problem on Hackerrank. Where I had to sort large numbers. So what I did was that I used collection.sort method and used custom comparator to sort the array. so my compare method was actually comparing string, since i cannot use int or double as range of numbers was bigger. What I noticed was that when I used sc.nextLine() to scan it did not pass all test cases. But when I used sc.next() it passed all test cases. Can anyone tell me reason behind this.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
     int x=sc.nextInt();sc.nextLine();

     List<String> list=new ArrayList();
     for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
         list.add(sc.next());
     }
    Collections.sort(list, (s1,s2) ->{
        if(s1.length()==s2.length())
           return s1.compareTo(s2);
           return s1.length()>s2.length()?1:-1;
                 } 
           );
     for(String str:list)
    System.out.println(str);


}
```

Comment: You aren't even supposed to touch the main method here?

Comment: next() stops taking input when the delimeter is reached which is by default a space , and nextline() stops taking input when you press the enter so spaces are also counted

Comment: I did not verify the timing, but it seems that `Scanner.nextLine()` uses a regular expression that is computationally more expensive than the one used by `Scanner.next()`. But: the input data is presented one item per line, so the fastest way to read the input would be using `BufferedReader.readLine()`